# Layout responsiveness issue in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, responsiveness

I have **xml** design with a Linear layout as root and inside this constraint layout is used.
I have an issue ([this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ5jh.png)) in *responsiveness* while using the layout validator. Please suggest me.

**LinearLayout and ConstraintLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

**FullName EdittextView**

```
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_full_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_start_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_end_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_pedittext"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_full_name"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_start_margin"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_full_name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_start_padding"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:textColorHint="#C0C0C0"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp" />
```

**Email EdittextView**

```
           <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_start_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_end_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_pedittext"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_icon_user"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_start_margin"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_start_padding"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:textColorHint="#C0C0C0"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp" />
        

 **Spinner for Country Option**

          <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/et_country_name"
            style="@style/SpinnerTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_start_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_end_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_50sdp" />
```

**Phone Number EditTextView**

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_phone_details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_start_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_end_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_pedittext"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_phone"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_start_margin"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_phone"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_start_padding"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:textColorHint="#C0C0C0"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp" />
```

**Date of birth calendar alert dialog popped out**

```
       <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_date_of_birth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_start_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_end_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_pedittext"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_dob"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_start_margin"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_dob"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_start_padding"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:textColorHint="#C0C0C0"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp" />
```

**EditTextView for password**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_start_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_end_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_pedittext"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_icon_password"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_start_margin"
    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_start_padding"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:textColorHint="#C0C0C0"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

**EditTextView for confirmpassword**

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_confirm_password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_start_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_end_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_pedittext"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_icon_password"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_start_margin"
    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:hint="@string/prompt_confirm_password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_start_padding"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:textColorHint="#C0C0C0"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

**constraintlayoutdesign**

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

**rombus image**
*Half rombus images (i.e 2 image) present in footer*

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:src="@drawable/mask_group"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

**signup button**

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_signUp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/sign_btn"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.835" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try weightSum in Linear layout and in it's child you can set the value of layout_weight.

For example: if you set the value of weightSum is equal to 10 then you can divide it's child like textview and imageview etc is equal to 6 and 4 respectively which is equal to 10.

for more help read this [article](https://programmer.help/blogs/summary-of-android-layout_weight-and-android-weight-sum.html)